# Catch python 'ImportError' if import from source directory

Tags: python, exception, importerror

When one tries to import a module `foo` while being in the source directory, one gets an rather confusing `ImportError` message: `ImportError: No module named foo`.

How can I easily catch this case and return a more informative message, e.g. 'Please do not load module foo from the source directory'?

Having the `__init__.py`, I would start with:

```
try:
    from _foo import *
except ImportError:
    ## check whether in the source directory...
```

So I would like to distinguish the different causes for an `ImportError` (e.g. because a module named `foo` is not installed at all), and detect the case in which the `setup.py` is located in the current directory.  What would be a elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`ImportError: No module named foo` actually means the module `foo.py` or package `foo/__init__.py` could not be found in any of the directories in the search path (`sys.path` list).

Since `sys.path` usually contains `.` (the current directory), that's probably what you meant by *being in the source directory*. You are in the top-level directory of package `foo` (where the `__init__.py` file is) so obviously you can't find `foo/__init__.py`.

Finally, you've answered your own question, more or less:

```
try:
    from _foo import *
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('<any message you want here>')
```

Alternatively, you could check the contents of `sys.path`, the current directory and, if known, the expected package directory and produce an even detailed and context-aware message.

Or add `..` to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (on Unix) to allow you to run from your source directory. Might even work on Windows, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'm rather looking for a way to check whether the `ImportError` is raised by the `setup.py` being located in the current directory and distinguish it from other cases.

Comment: So use the second option I mentioned. You know which package you are trying to import (as a last resort, extract it from the `ImportError` message) and you can get the current directory name. The condition you are looking for corresponds to the package and directory name being the same, no?